# Solspace: Calendar

Tags: solspace-calendar

I have a mini Solspace calendar that shows correctly [here](http://mobilearts.org/calendar/), but does not display all days of the month [here](http://mobilearts.org/calendar/search-results/5dfeee391077af45181027f0c3cfe7f8/).

Here is the code:

```
   <div id="mc_wrap">
{exp:calendar:cal
{if segment_2 == "calendars"}
date_range_start="year-month-01" date_range_end="year-month-last"
{/if}
{if segment_2 == "edit"}
date_range_start="year-month-01" date_range_end="year-month-last"
{/if}
{if segment_2 == "create"}
date_range_start="year-month-01" date_range_end="year-month-last"
{/if}
{if segment_2 == "event"}
date_range_start="year-month-01" date_range_end="year-month-last"
{/if}
{if segment_2 == ""}
date_range_start="year-month-01" date_range_end="year-month-last"
{/if}
{if segment_2 == "month"}
{if segment_3 == ''}date_range_start="year-month-01" date_range_end="year-month-last"{/if}
{if segment_3 != ''}date_range_start="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-01" date_range_end="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-last"{/if}
{/if}
{if segment_2 == "week"}
{if segment_3 == ''}date_range_start="year-month-01" date_range_end="year-month-last"{/if}
{if segment_3 != ''}date_range_start="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-01" date_range_end="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-last"{/if}
{/if}
{if segment_2 == "day"}
{if segment_3 == ''}date_range_start="year-month-01" date_range_end="year-month-last"{/if}
{if segment_3 != ''}date_range_start="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-01" date_range_end="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-last"{/if}
{/if}
dynamic="off"
}
<div id="mc_calendar">
{display_each_month}
<table id="mini-cal">
<thead>
<tr  id="mc_head">
<th colspan="1">{if segment_2 != "calendars"}<a id="mc_prev_month" class="icon left" href="{path=''}mini-cal/month/{prev_month format="%Y/%m"}/">&laquo;</a>{/if}</th>

<th colspan="5"><a href="{path='calendar'}/{month format="%Y/%m"}/">{month format="%F %Y"}</a></th>

<th colspan="1">{if segment_2 != "calendars"}<a id="mc_next_month" class="icon right" href="{path=''}mini-cal/month/{next_month format="%Y/%m"}/"> &raquo;</a>{/if}</th>
</tr>
<tr id="mc_days">
{display_each_day_of_week}
<th class="{if day_of_week_is_weekend}weekend{/if} {if day_of_week_is_current}current{/if}">{day_of_week_one}</th>
{/display_each_day_of_week}
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{display_each_week}
<tr>
{display_each_day}
<td class="
{if !day_in_current_month == FALSE}mc_pad{/if}
{if day_event_total > 0}has_events{/if}
{if count == 7}selected{/if}
{if day_is_today}today{/if}
"><div class="mc_date">{if day_in_current_month}
{if day_event_total}<a href="{path='calendar/day'}/{day format="%Y/%m/%d"}/">{/if}
{day}
{if day_event_total}</a>{/if}
{if:else}
<strong class="middot">&middot;</strong>
{/if}</div></td>
{/display_each_day}
</tr>
{/display_each_week}
</tbody>
</table>
{/display_each_month}
</div>
{/exp:calendar:cal}
</div>
```

Not sure what I am missing here but I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a check for the "search-results" segment:

```
{if segment_2 == "search-results"}
   date_range_start="year-month-01" date_range_end="year-month-last"
{/if}
```